# Replacing tokens in free-text only between certain other tokens in the text in Java

Tags: java, token, stringbuilder

I have a situation in a free-text file, where between any pair of two string matches of my choice - e.g.

```
<hello> and </hello>
```

I want to replace the occurrence of a third string-match with a different string e.g. '=' with '&EQ;'

e.g.

```
hi=I want this equals sign to stay the same,but=<hello>
<I want="this one in the hello tag to be replaced"/>
</hello>,and=of course this one outside the tag to stay the same
```

becomes

```
hi=I want this equals sign to stay the same,but=<hello>
<I want&EQ;"this one in the hello tag to be replaced"/>
</hello>,and=of course this one outside the tag to stay the same
```

Basically this is because an XML body is being sent in a value-pair and it is royally screwing things up (I am sent this format by a venue and don't have control over it

My immediate approach was to start with a BufferedReader and parse into a StringBuilder going through line by line using String.indexOf( ) to toggle on and off whether we are in  tags or not, but 20 minutes in to this approach it occurred to me this may be a bit brute-force and there might be an existing solution to this kind of problem

I know this approach will work eventually but my question is, is there a better way (that is one that is higher level and uses existing Java libraries / common frameworks e.g. Apache Commons, etc. which would make it less error-prone and more maintainable. I.e. is there a more intelligent way of solving this problem than the approach I am taking? Which is effectively brute-force parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to escape XML, have a look at Apache Commons Lang StringEscapeUtils, specifically [StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29), it should do what you need.

Comment: the fact it looked a lot like an escape character was kind of incidental, it was more the structure of replaceing a particular string with another only within a se tof specific tokens in itself that I was trying to solve. So this wasn't quite my question. I've posted the solution I came up with anyway, but I dont think it's a great one

Answer (score 0):

My great impenetrable solution is as follows, and it seems to work.

I do apologise that it's so hard to follow but it basically came down to this from factorising and re-factorising, many times over combining similar pieces of code.

It will replace all the occurences of String 'replace' with String 'with' between tokens of 'openToken' and 'closeToken' and should be started with mode=false to begin with

As with most things in life, there's probably a really clever succinct way to do this with RegEx

```
boolean mode=false
StringBuilder output

while( String line = newLine ) {
    mode = bodge( "<hello>", "</hello>", "=", "&EQ;", output, mode );
}



private static boolean bodge( String openToken, String closeToken, String replace, String with, String line, StringBuilder out, boolean mode  ) {

    String comparator = mode ? closeToken : openToken;

    int index = line.indexOf( comparator );

    // drop through straight if nothing interesting
    if( index == -1 ) {
        String outLine = mode ?
                             replacer( line , replace, with ) :
                             line;
        out.append( outLine );
        out.append( "\r\n" );
        return mode;
    }
    else {
        int endOfToken = index + comparator.length();
        String outLine = line.substring(0, endOfToken);
        outLine = mode ?
                      replacer( outLine , replace, with ) :
                      outLine;

        out.append(outLine );
        return bodge( openToken, closeToken, replace, with, line.substring( endOfToken ), out, !mode );
    }
}
```